# String JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I have some question regarding javascript, I want to write a function to have an output like this
example:

input:

```
["Enter uid1234 Muzi", "Enter uid4567 Prodo", "Leave uid1234", "Enter uid1234 Prodo", "Change uid4567 Ryan"]
```

answer:

```
["Prodo came in.", "Ryan came in.", "Prodo has left.", "Prodo came in."]
```

I write function like this

```js
function solution([enters, id, name], [enters, id, name]) {

  for (let i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
    if (enters === "leave") {
      console.log(`${name} ${id} is leaving`)
    }
  }
}

solution(["leave", "uid23", "test"], ["leave", "uid23", "tester2"]);
//result "test uid23 is leaving"
```

(i want it to show the tester2 too.)

but its just showing the first array of the solution output, how to make it like the examples?? pls help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write a title that summarizes the specific problem. *"String JavaScript"* is not searchable for future readers. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution([enters, id, name]) {

  for (let i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
    if (enters === "leave") {
      console.log(`${name} ${id} is leaving`)
    }
  }
}
 

solution(["leave", "uid23", "test"]);
solution(["leave", "uid23", "tester2"]);
//result "test uid23 is leaving"
```

if you have more than 1 inputs you can use for loop.

Comment: From where you get the inputs?